# Reading a file and accumulating info into a dictionary in Python 3

Tags: dictionary

I have been working on this for a few days and I can't get it to work. I am trying to read a file and accumulate some info into three different dictionary. This is an assignment for an archived online class, and the solution to this was not posted.

Here is the file to read from: It starts below.

```
Restaurant name to rating:
# dict of {str: int}
{'Georgie Porgie': 87%,
'Queen St. Cafe': 82%,
'Dumplings R Us': 71%,
'Mexican Grill': 85%,
'Deep Fried Everything': 52%}

Price to list of restaurant names:
# dict of {str, list of str}
{'$': ['Queen St. Cafe', 'Dumplings R Us', 'Deep Fried Everything'],
'$$': ['Mexican Grill'],
'$$$': ['Georgie Porgie'],
'$$$$': []}

Cuisine to list of restaurant names:
# dict of {str, list of str}
{'Canadian': ['Georgie Porgie'],
'Pub Food': ['Georgie Porgie', 'Deep Fried Everything'],
'Malaysian': ['Queen St. Cafe'],
'Thai': ['Queen St. Cafe'],
'Chinese': ['Dumplings R Us'],
'Mexican': ['Mexican Grill']  (--->Ends here, this part is not included).
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
 def read_restaurants(file):
  """ (file) -> (dict, dict, dict)

 Return a tuple of three dictionaries based on the information in the file:

  - a dict of {restaurant name: rating%}
  - a dict of {price: list of restaurant names}
  - a dict of {cusine: list of restaurant names}
  """

  # Initiate dictionaries
  name_to_rating = {}
  price_to_names = {'$': [], '$$': [], '$$$': [], '$$$$': []}
  cuisine_to_names = {}

  # Open the file
  with open('restaurant_file_above.txt','r') as file:

  # Build line list
  lines = file.read().splitlines()



   # Process the file    
   for i in range(0,len(lines),5):
     # Read individual data
     name = lines[i]
     rating = int(lines[i+1].strip('%')) #error occurs here
     price = lines[i+2]
     cuisines = lines[i+3].split( ',' )

     # Assign rating to name
     name_to_rating[name]=rating;

     # Assign names to price
     price_to_names[price].append(name)

     # Assign names to cuisine
     for cuisine in cuisines:
        cuisine_to_names.setdefault(cuisine,[]).append(name)

  return name_to_rating, price_to_names, cuisine_to_names
```

I am a beginner, so some guidance is greatly appreciated. I just don't know what else to try. I am using Python 3.4.2 by the way.

Comment: The original file did not contain the '%' signs by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The file you are trying to read is the final output, not the original. Below is one solution with the original data in the docstring.

```
def read_restaurants(filename):
  """ (file) -> (dict,dict,dict)

  Return a tuple of three dictionaries based on the information in the file below

  Georgie Porgie
  87%
  $$$
  Canadian, Pub Food

  Queen St. Cafe
  82%
  $
  Malaysian, Thai

  Dumplings R Us
  71%
  $
  Chinese

  Mexican Grill
  85%
  $$
  Mexian

  Deep Fried Everything
  52%
  $
  Pub Food

  - a dict of {restaurant name: rating}
  - a dict of {price: list of restaurant names}
  - a dict of {cusine: list of restaurant names}
  """

  name_to_rating = {}
  price_to_names = {'$':[],'$$':[],'$$$':[],'$$$$':[]}
  cuisine_to_names = {}

  #set incrementing number
  i = 1
  with open(filename,'rU') as f:
    for line in f:
      #check if blank line
      if line.strip():
        line = line.strip('\n')

        #determine restaurant_name
        if i == 1:
          restaurant_name = line

        #create dictionaries with restaurant_name
        if i == 2:
          rating = line
          name_to_rating[restaurant_name] = rating
        elif i == 3:
          price = line
          price_to_names[price].append(restaurant_name)
        elif i == 4:
          #could be multiple cuisines for each restaurant_name
          cuisine_list = line.split(',')
          for cuisine in cuisine_list:
            cuisine_to_names[cuisine] = restaurant_name

      #at blank line start increment over
      else:
        i = 0
      i += 1

  print name_to_rating
  print price_to_names
  print cuisine_to_names

  return (name_to_rating,price_to_names,cuisine_to_names)

def main():
  return read_restaurants('restaurants.txt')

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think above answer does not save cuisine_by_names dictionary correctly. See below code. This works:

```
def read_restuarants(file):
    name_to_rating={}
    price_to_names={'$':[],'$$':[],'$$$':[], '$$$$':[]}
    cuisine_to_names={}
    i=1
    with open(file) as f:
        contents = f.readlines()
        for line in contents:
            if line.strip():
                l = line.strip()
                if i ==1:
                    rest_name = l
                if i ==2:
                    rating=l
                    name_to_rating[rest_name]=rating
                if i==3:
                    price=l
                    price_to_names[l].append(rest_name)
                if i==4:
                    cuisine_list = l.split(',')
                    for cuisine in cuisine_list:
                        if cuisine not in cuisine_to_names.keys():
                            cuisine_to_names[cuisine] = [rest_name]
                        else:
                            cuisine_to_names[cuisine].append(rest_name)
            else:
                i=0
            i=i+1
        print name_to_rating
        print price_to_names
        print cuisine_to_names
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved mine.

I'm going to share it here because I didn't find any solution online.

I broke the whole file into words and saved them in 'lines' variable and used a while loop taking into account that:

```
lines[i] = restaurant name
lines[i+1] = rating
lines[i+2] = price
lines[i+3] = cuisine
lines[i+4] = blank
```

So I worked with above data and at the end of while loop I just increment 'i' by 5.

Here's the whole thing, including read_restaurant:

```
# The file containing the restaurant data.
FILENAME = 'restaurants_small.txt'


def recommend(file, price, cuisines_list):
    """(file open for reading, str, list of str) -> list of [int, str] list

    Find restaurants in file that are priced according to price and that are
    tagged with any of the items in cuisines_list.  Return a list of lists of
    the form [rating%, restaurant name], sorted by rating%.
    """

    # Read the file and build the data structures.
    # - a dict of {restaurant name: rating%}
    # - a dict of {price: list of restaurant names}
    # - a dict of {cusine: list of restaurant names}
    name_to_rating, price_to_names, cuisine_to_names = read_restaurants(file)

    # Retrieves all restaurants matching specific price tag (e.g. '$') from 'price' argument
    names_matching_price = price_to_names[price]

    # Get restaurant names (from above price tag) that also belong to cuisine in cuisines_list 
    names_final = filter_by_cuisine(names_matching_price, cuisine_to_names, cuisines_list)

    # Retrieve ratings from restaurants in names_final and return sorted output by ratings
    result = build_rating_list(name_to_rating, names_final)

    return result

def build_rating_list(name_to_rating, names_final):
    """ (dict of {str: int}, list of str) -> list of list of [int, str]

    Return a list of [rating%, restaurant name], sorted by rating%

    >>> name_to_rating = {'Georgie Porgie': 87,
     'Queen St. Cafe': 82,
     'Dumplings R Us': 71,
     'Mexican Grill': 85,
     'Deep Fried Everything': 52}
    >>> names = ['Queen St. Cafe', 'Dumplings R Us']
    [[82, 'Queen St. Cafe'], [71, 'Dumplings R Us']]
    """
    # For each restaurant in names_final, append corresponding rating (sorted) first to result
    result = list()
    for restaurant in names_final:
        result.append([name_to_rating[restaurant],restaurant])
    return sorted(result,reverse=True)



def filter_by_cuisine(names_matching_price, cuisine_to_names, cuisines_list):
    """ (list of str, dict of {str: list of str}, list of str) -> list of str

    >>> names = ['Queen St. Cafe', 'Dumplings R Us', 'Deep Fried Everything']
    >>> cuis = 'Canadian': ['Georgie Porgie'],
     'Pub Food': ['Georgie Porgie', 'Deep Fried Everything'],
     'Malaysian': ['Queen St. Cafe'],
     'Thai': ['Queen St. Cafe'],
     'Chinese': ['Dumplings R Us'],
     'Mexican': ['Mexican Grill']}
    >>> cuisines = ['Chinese', 'Thai']
    >>> filter_by_cuisine(names, cuis, cuisines)
    ['Queen St. Cafe', 'Dumplings R Us']
    """
    # For each cuisine we want, check if the names within price range belong to that cuisine
    result = list()
    # For each name that is in cuisines_list, we check if restaurant name is in there and return it
    for cuisine in cuisines_list:
        for name in names_matching_price:
            if name in cuisine_to_names[cuisine] and name not in result:
                result.append(name)
    return result

def read_restaurants(file):
    """ (file) -> (dict, dict, dict)

    Return a tuple of three dictionaries based on the information in the file:

    - a dict of {restaurant name: rating%}
    - a dict of {price: list of restaurant names}
    - a dict of {cusine: list of restaurant names}
    """
    name_to_rating = {}
    price_to_names = {'$': [], '$$': [], '$$$': [], '$$$$': []}
    cuisine_to_names = {}
    with open(file) as f:
        i = 0
        # Store all lines (without \n) to lines in a list of words
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        while i < len(lines):
            # we know the following:
            # line[i] = restaurant name, line[i+1] = rating
            # line[i+2] = price, line[i+3] = cuisine
            name_to_rating[lines[i]] = lines[i+1]
            # match price to name
            if lines[i+2] not in price_to_names.keys():
                price_to_names[lines[i+2]] = [lines[i]]
            else:
                price_to_names[lines[i+2]].append(lines[i])
            # add list of restaurants per cuisine
            cuisines = lines[i+3].split(',')
            for cuisine in cuisines:
                if cuisine not in cuisine_to_names.keys():
                    cuisine_to_names[cuisine] = [lines[i]]
                else:
                    cuisine_to_names[cuisine].append(lines[i])
            # while loop is incremented by 5 as name is in position 0, rating 1, price 2, cuisine 3, blank line 4 
            i += 5
    return name_to_rating, price_to_names, cuisine_to_names
```